# Looping through two object arrays to push matching values to a new array doesn't work in React but does in JS Fiddle

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have two data sets that vary in length. I need to loop through both arrays and push the photo url of the matching player ID's to a new array. I am doing this **after** the API data has loaded into my React component, so it does not seem to be a matter of the data not being loaded yet. I can `console.log` both data sets and see that they are successfully being returned from the API. All of this works in JS Fiddle (link below), but not React. So I am having a tough time tracking down what is going on.

Here are my data sets (all of them have obviously been shortened):

This object array is returned from an API endpoint that holds all of the player information, such as ID, Photo URL's, etc etc. (this is 1200+ objects):

```
playerInfo = [
 {PlayerID: 123, PhotoURL: url123},
 {PlayerID: 345, PhotoURL: url345},
 {PlayerID: 678, PhotoURL: url678},
 {PlayerID: 910, PhotoURL: url910},
 {PlayerID: 1112, PhotoURL: "url1112"},
 {PlayerID: 1213, PhotoURL: "url1213"}
];
```

This data is returned from a separate API endpoint that lists the current leaders (returns top 40 leaders):

```
playerIDs = [123, 345, 678, 910]
```

Unfortunately this leaderboard data does not include the photo URL's with the returned player ID's, so I have to compare the player IDs in both arrays, and then push the PhotoURL from the above matching `playerInfo` array.

My approach is as follows(I probably could be using some type of ES6 feature for this, so please let me know if that's the case.):

```
let leaderPhotos = [];

for(let i = 0; i < playerInfo.length; i++) {
  if(playerInfo[i].PlayerID === playerIDs[i]) {
    leaderPhotos.push(playerInfo[i].PhotoURL);
  }
}
```

My thinking for this is that even though the `playerIDs` array is shorter than the `PlayerInfo` array, setting the loop to the length of the `PlayerInfo` array will allow the shorter `PlayerIDs` leaderboard array to be compared against every player ID in the `PlayerInfo` object array since any player could be on the leaderboard at any given time. If a Player ID matches within both arrays, it pushes the photo URL value of the `PlayerInfo` object to an array, that I can then use to load in top leader photos. Since the loop goes in order through the leaderboard `PlayerIDs`, the returned photo URL's are in order of the leader board.

Here it is working in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9scavoLd/4/).
You can see in the console that it only pushes the photo URL's of the matching player ID's. Perfect, just what I want.

However when this same thing is applied inside of the React component responsible for handling the API data, I am getting back an empty array in the console after the logic has run it's course. I can `console.log` both of the returned API data sets to see that I am successfully getting data back to work with.

I was messing around, and decided to see if setting both array indexs to a value would work like so:

```
let leaderPhotos = [];

      if(playerInfo[0].PlayerID === playerIDs[0]) {
        leaderPhotos.push(playerInfo[0].PhotoURL);
      } else {
         return false;
      } console.log(leaderPhotos);
```

And sure enough, this will push the matching pair's photo url to leaderPhotos as expected **without** the for loop. I am having a difficult time understanding why the for loop is not working, even though in JS Fiddle it proves that this should return the desired results. Thanks for any tips in advance!

Comment: Could you provide your react component code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Short clean version**

```
const leaderPhotos = playerIDs.map(id => 
    playerInfo.find(({ PlayerID }) => PlayerID === id).PhotoURL
);
```

Note: Just to let you know this is a nested loop. Where `map` is a loop through the leadership board and `find` is a loop through the players. The time complexity is **O(n * m)** where **n** is the total users and **m** is the length of the leadership board.

> Though if the total number of users isn't huge it shouldn't matter and as long as the code looks clean and understandable that would always be better (:

If you have a **HUGE** number of users and you want to have the most **efficient** code. What you should do is store your playerInfo in a map/object where the key is the playerId and the value is the playerURL. This way it only needs to loop through your objects once and has a **O(1)** retrieval for the player photos.

> **Efficient Version**

```
const playerMap = {};

playerInfo.forEach((player) => {
  playerMap[player.PlayerID] = player.PhotoURL;
});

const leaderPhotos = playerIDs.map(leaderId => playerMap[leaderId]);
```

The time complexity of this is at most **O(n)** where **n** is the number of players.

Comment: Your first solution gives an error in JSFiddle. Can you please check with the code?

Comment: Oops! Thanks! I was mainly trying to do pseudo code and didn't see the JSFiddle

Comment: This worked for me perfect. I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let leaderPhotos = playerInfo.filter(plr => playerIDs.indexOf(plr.PlayerID) !== -1).map( t => t.PhotoURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both of your arrays have the same order based on `playerId`.

Otherwise, you need to use two loops:

```
let leaderPhotos = [];

for(let i = 0; i < playerInfo.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < playerIDs.length; j++ )
    if(playerInfo[i].PlayerID === playerIDs[j]) {
      leaderPhotos.push(playerInfo[i].PhotoURL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so this is the shortest solution possible compared to the other answers:

```
let leaderPhotos = playerInfo.filter((info) => playerIDs.includes(info.PlayerID)).map(id => id.PhotoURL);
```